# Angular and Firebase Content Flicker

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I currently have an Angular app using AngularFire for Firebase.

When a user logs in or simply loads a new route there is a flicker whilst the page loads gets the data back from Firebase.

It means my content is filled with gaps whilst it waits for the $scope variables to appear/update.

Ideally I would like to show a spinner or just use Ng-cloak but I presume because the data is async the application believes that the page is ready and serves it up.

Is there anyway I can tell the application to only complete loading when initial dataset is back from Firebase?

Thanks!

Comment: Data becomes available as complete nodes that you monitor are downloaded. You can show alternative content until all data is available, but that has little to do with Firebase. And it also depends on how you bind the data into your view. Either way: unless you show a minimal example of your problem, it will be hard to give concrete help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at [ngCloack](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak), if this is the kind of flickeing you're experiencing

Comment: Yup, that looks like one way. I often use `ng-show` and `ng-hide`, but ang-cloak` seems better for initial data loading. Quite often you can also prevent premature content display by using `ng-bind` instead of `{{property}}` binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `ng-hide` class to the element tag which has dynamic data loading

`<section class="ng-hide" ng-show="contentLoadedScopeVariable">
    Async Content
  </section>`